# Windows Installer - Silently Installing Prerequisites

Tags: windows, installation, outlook-addin

So here is my dilemma. I need to create an install for an office addin that can be pushed out to the company through AD/Group Policy. I have to work with the following limitations:

- All prerequisites have to be installed, silently
- Everything needs to be done via one executable (so we're
  bootstrapping the prerequisites)
- All of this is going to have to be wrapped in an MSI so our sys
  admins can push it out through GPO.

I've managed to get the exe set up, and it works except that the prerequisites are not being installed silently (I'm calling "setup.exe /qn"). I'm still having to accept the EULA for the "Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime" install. I've done quite a bit of searching and managed to find this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwade/archive/2007/11/29/how-to-update-the-bootstrapper-to-accept-command-line-arguments.aspx which says I can't avoid the EULA but it was written in '07 and so I wanted to see if anything had changed or anyone knew of a way to do this.

Essentially what I'm asking at this point is how can I get the bootstrapper to do a silent install of the 2010 VSTOR so that users will not be prompted with the EULA.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like that probably would violate the EULA.

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes use [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to manually modify installers and remove these types of dialogs.